# How do you update directive html and compile so that angular responds?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonicblis/99r7v/9/) with my broken code.

I've created a simple little directive (by no means complete) that presents a date picker in the most simple way possible.  When bound to a scope property, the property can be updated by clicking on a day.  So far, so good.  Of course you need to be able to look at other months.  This is where things get tricky.  I'm regenerating the HTML that's tied to the template: property when someone clicks the '<' or '>' next to the date at the top.  When I do so, I'm trying to $compile so that all the angular wire-up still functions as expected, but I'm missing something about how my $compile operation is changing the element.  I'm using this to compile the new HTML:

```
element.replaceWith($compile(getCalHMTL(month, year))(scope));
```

That works and everything is wired up for a second call, but when the second call is made (by clicking on the '>' or '<' a second time), I get the following error message:

```
Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null
```

as if element is null in the link: property.  How should I be using $compile to make this work in this example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you compile the html, element isn't being updated with what the newly compiled html is.
If you reassign element to the newly compiled html it will work.

```
scope.ChangeMonth = function(month, year){
    var compiled = $compile(getCalHMTL(month, year))(scope);
    element.replaceWith(compiled);
    element = compiled;
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle using that which works: http://jsfiddle.net/Pj3f2/